# Multiple comparison

Tags: t-test

Having this model. goo.gl/1niZiF
The same group of people underwent a specific intervention. The effect of this intervention is measured by three different dependent variables with pre and post tests. I need just to compare those pre and post tests three time for each dependent variable separately. Ideally it seems that running 3 times a t-test is a simple solution. But then familywise error rate will be increased. What test could be used as alternative? Manova? But then again it requires a specific fixed factor which, here, is not so important.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a single group, you could try using the following test statistic on the difference vectors $\boldsymbol{x}_i$, which can be transformed into an $F$ statistic:

$$t^2 = \frac{n}{n - 1}\left( \bar{\boldsymbol{x}} - \boldsymbol{\mu} \right)^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \left( \bar{\boldsymbol{x}} - \boldsymbol{\mu} \right)$$

where $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ is the sample covariance between the three outputs and $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is the mean difference in your null hypothesis (here, just the zero vector).

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution#Statistic